# Angular2: ngClass is not working on page load

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my code:

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {    
    this.customer = service.getData();     
    console.log(this.customer.address.postalAddress.streetAddress.length);                
  }


<input required [(ngModel)]="customer.address.postalAddress.streetAddress" 
       [ngClass]="{'ng-dirty': customer.address.postalAddress.streetAddress.length > 0}">
```

Inside console browser logs 15 which is number of counted address length yet css class is not applied.

> Css is applied only when on purpose reset customer object and again
>   set data, on page load is not working.

Comment: overall looks usual, please create a plunkr reproducing the problem

Answer (score 2):

You most probably need a resolver or change detection. Or preferably both.

What happens is the **page gets initialized before your data is loaded in** and not checked again until you reset the customer object. Resolve would allow you to grab data before you activate a route and component thus eliminating that problem.

https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data - here's angular official guide on how to use resolvers.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html - I also would suggest reading up and using change detection. Helps identify and eliminate problems like this.