# using async pipe to the property on template

Tags: javascript, angular

```
export class MyClass {
    data: MyData;  
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
      this.dataService.getData().subscribe((myData) => {
        this.data = myData;
      });  
    }
}
```

data is successfully retrieved trough web service. MyData object has property firstName which I want to represent inside template using async pipe.

I tried with

```
<input required [ngModel]="data.firstName | async" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="firstName">
```

this approach doesn't bind property to the template at all, `[(ngModel)]="data.firstName"` works but I've been told that this approach cannot be used together with async pipe.

**Update:**

```
getData(): Observable<MyData>{
        return Observable.from([this.fakeData()]
            .map(res=>res as MyData));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

```
export class MyClass {
    data: Promise;  
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {    
      this.data = this.dataService.getData()
    }
}
```

The `| async` pipe is already the subscribing

with

```
<input required [ngModel]="(data | async)?.firstName" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="firstName">
```

or with your code

```
<input required [ngModel]="data?.firstName" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name="firstName">
```

where I just added `?` to avoid an error while the data is not yet available.

Comment: When I tried first approach following error is displayed in console: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: Sounds like `getData()` doesn't return a Promise or Observable

Comment: What about the 2nd approach? I wouldn't expect it to work either, if the 1st doesn't work, but I'm interested in what error it produces.

Comment: Question is updated with data retrieval part trough service. Second approach actually bind the data but I'm still not sure how can I test async feature. I'm struggling to set conditional css class using ngClass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282864/angular2-ngclass-is-not-working-on-page-load

Comment: Thanks for this, but can I actually use MyData instead of Observable<MyData> on app.component.ts. I need to manipulate MyData object further once I retrieve it.

Comment: You can use `this.data = this.dataService.getData().map((md) => md.fullName = md.givenName + ' ' + md.familyName))`

Comment: I understand. Perfect.

Comment: If you use `{}` like  `(md) => { /* code here */ }` you can have as much code as you want. Just ensure that you return the value you want `| async` to receive.